# Refactor using C++14

Tags: refactoring, c++14

The task is pretty simple, but I am wondering how to refactor this code using C++14. The input is structure A, and the output is structure B, that contains array of structures C. A field someNumber of structure C gets value if someNumber exists, otherwise '0' is assigned.

```
struct A
{
    size_t numberOfItems{5};
    int idList[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
};

struct B
{
    size_t numberOfItems;
    C listOfCStructures[5];
};

struct C
{
    int id;
    int someNumber;
};

int getRandomInt() 
{
    return rand() % 100;
}

bool doesSomeNumberExist(int id)
{
    ... // some implementation
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < a.numberOfItems; ++index)
    {
        auto id = a.idList[index];
        if (doesSomeNumberExist(id))
        {
            b.listOfCStructures[index] = {a.idList[index], getRandomInt()};
        }
        else
        {
            b.listOfCStructures[index] = {a.idList[index], 0};
        }
        b.numberOfItems++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What here needs to be "refactored"? What will that accomplish? What's the goal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on SoftwareEngineering.

Comment: I assumed that the for loop can be refactored somehow using lambdas and algorithms.

Comment: Why would it need to be? It's just a `for` loop. And yes, you could use range-based `for`, and while that's less repetition, I don't really see the overall point.

Comment: Actually ranged-based for doesn't work fine for indexes. Thank you for your answers. I just ensured myself that it cannot be written in a modern way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... if I'm not wrong, in the initial value of `numberOfItems` in

```
struct B
{
    size_t numberOfItems;
    C listOfCStructures[5];
};
```

is undefined.

And your code doesn't initialize it. So when you increment it

```
b.numberOfItems++;
```

you're incrementing an undefined value.

I suggest to initialize the value with `0`

```
struct B
{
    size_t numberOfItems { 0U };
    C listOfCStructures[5];
};
```

Said this... you can simplify your loop as follows

```
   for ( auto index = 0U ; index < a.numberOfItems ; ++index)
    {
      auto id = a.idList[index];

      b.listOfStructures[index]
        = { id, doesSomeNumberExist(id) ? getRandomInt() : 0 };
    }

   b.numberOfItems = a.numberOfItems;
```

But sorry: nothing C++14 specific.

Comment: Thank you, as I commented above, good to know that I haven't missed anything.